# Auto number of unique field

Tags: java

Do u have any ideas how to generate auto number in java? I need to use it for guest ID. Every time I add a new guest, each guest has a unique ID. Help is greatly appreciated

Many Thanks

Comment: Just increment a counter.

Answer (score 2):

### Counter

You can increment your ID and treat it as counter

- [Beginner Java Counter Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18819066/beginner-java-counter-code)

### [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)

You can also generate unique String with [`UUID.randomUUID()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID())

> Static factory to retrieve a type 4 (pseudo randomly generated) UUID. The UUID is generated using a cryptographically strong pseudo random number generator.

UUID numbers are unique and described in [RFC 4122](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt)

**Sample usage**

```
String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
```

### JPA

For JPA Entity simply use [@GeneratedValue](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/GeneratedValue.html)

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) 
    long id;

}
```

- [JPA primary key auto generate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817625/jpa-primary-key-auto-generate)

Answer (score 1):

import java.util.UUID;

public class GenerateUUID {

```
public static final void main(String... aArgs){
//generate random UUIDs
    UUID idOne = UUID.randomUUID();
    UUID idTwo = UUID.randomUUID();
    log("UUID One: " + idOne);
    log("UUID Two: " + idTwo);
}

private static void log(Object aObject){
    System.out.println( String.valueOf(aObject) );
}
```

}

taken from: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=56

Comment: This is different from my answer in any way? :)

Comment: was my first post:P was busy figuring out the formatting and all that, still didnt get it right! by then you already posted heh

Comment: ok, I upvote your answer, good job :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AutoNumber {
    private int counter = 0;
    public int getNumber() {
        int tmp = counter;
        counter++;
        return tmp;
    }
}
```